# Using R to calculate trumpet curves from flow data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to calculate Trumpet Curves from intravenous set flow data using R (and preferably ggplot2 although that's not vital). Here is some flow data from fluid warming pumps: http://pastebin.com/vJmGcJmn

So far I have this:

```
flow<-read.table(file="flow.dat",header=T)
flow$diff<-c(0,diff(flow$Mass))
ggplot(data=flow, aes(x=Secs,y=diff)) + geom_line()
```

Note that the trumpet graphs required are as per ISO 60601-2-24 (if that means anything!)

This flow was set up at 150ml/minute.

Comment: Care to give us some data to play with? It shouldn't be hard. Two geom_point, two geom_abline and two geom_line calls and you're there.

Comment: Added some pastebin data to the post.

Comment: What is the expected dose per interval here?

Comment: 150ml per minute.  (150g/min is fine - I'm not bothered about the correction factor at present).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry this took so long, pressed for time.

The data you provided don't seem to fit your description of what the trumpet curve's suppose to represent or I'm missing something big. I would appreciate it if you could, in short, describe what needs to be done with the data.

When you manage to shape your data for output, you can stick it into the code below and it should produce a plot. I'll make it up to you to customize it to your needs.

```
# generate some random data
trump <- data.frame(
   curve1 = rev(sort(rchisq(100, df = 2))) * rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 0.1) + 3,
   curve2 = -rev(sort(rchisq(100, df = 2))) * rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 0.1) - 3
)
trump <- trump[seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 3), ]

ggplot(trump, aes(x = 1:nrow(trump), y = curve1)) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_point() +
   geom_line(aes(y = curve2)) + 
   geom_point(aes(y = curve2)) +
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype = "solid") + # overall percentage error
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), linetype = "dashed") + # set rate
   xlab("Observation windows (in minutes)") +
   ylab("% error") + 
   annotate("text", x = 8, y = -1.5, label = "overall percentage error") +
   annotate("text", x = 5, y = 3, label = "set rate") +
   annotate("text", x = 10, y = -24, label = "min. error") +
   annotate("text", x = 10, y = 24, label = "max. error") +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @roman-lustrik. Many many thanks for that answer.  I can see how to generate the graphs now.  My only missing part is the intermediate step - how to calculate the max and min error rates for a particular observation window.   We now have some data from the pumps we need to test - http://pastebin.com/AUD1fQfF.         The standard requires calculation of Ep(max.) and Ep(min.) for the 2 min, 5 min, 11 min, 19 min and 31 min observation windows
If you need more data please email petesmtl at gmail.com.  Your help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE 16/07/2012: I have made a great deal of progress with this today - no need for any more help at the moment - I just need to put it into  a format I can place up here.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Roman for his help. This is the way we ended up doing it.

```
flow<-read.table("iv.txt",comment.char="#",header=TRUE)
Q<-as.data.frame(c(0,(60*diff(flow$wt,1,1)/0.5)))  # Q is used for flow in  the standard
names(Q)<-"Q"
# Now combine them
l<-list(flow,Q)
dflow<-as.data.frame(l)
t1flow<-subset(dflow, dflow$secs>60*60 & dflow$secs<=120*60) # require the second hour of the data
t1flow$QE<-((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100  # calculate the error
library(TTR) # use this for moving averages
# 
# Avert your eyes!  I know there must be a slicker way of doing this .....
#     
# Calculate the moving average using a sample rate of every 4 readings (2 mins of 30sec readings)
QE2<-SMA(t1flow$QE,4)
minQE2<-min(QE2,na.rm=TRUE)
maxQE2<-max(QE2,na.rm=TRUE)
# now for the 5 minute window
QE5<-SMA(t1flow$QE,10)
minQE5<-min(QE5,na.rm=TRUE)
maxQE5<-max(QE5,na.rm=TRUE)
# Set window to 11 mins
QE11<-SMA(t1flow$QE,22)
minQE11<-min(QE11,na.rm=TRUE)
maxQE11<-max(QE11,na.rm=TRUE)
# Set window to 19 mins
QE19<-SMA(t1flow$QE,38)
minQE19<-min(QE19,na.rm=TRUE)
maxQE19<-max(QE19,na.rm=TRUE)
# Set window to 31 mins
QE31<-SMA(t1flow$QE,62)
minQE31<-min(QE31,na.rm=TRUE)
maxQE31<-max(QE31,na.rm=TRUE)
# 
# OK - you can look again :-)
#
# create a data frame from this data
trump<-data.frame(c(2,5,11,19,31),c(minQE2,minQE5,minQE11,minQE19,minQE31),c(maxQE2,maxQE5,maxQE11,maxQE19,maxQE31))
names(trump)<-c("T","minE","maxE")
A<-mean(t1flow$QE) # calculate the overall mean percentage error
error_caption<-paste("overall percentage error = ",A,"%") # create the string to label the error line
# plot the graph
ggplot(trump, aes(x = T, y = minE)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(color="red") +
    geom_line(aes(y = maxE)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = maxE),colour="red") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype = "dashed") + # overall percentage error
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = A), linetype = "solid") + # set rate
    xlab("Observation windows (in minutes)") +
    ylab("% error") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,5,11,19,31),limits=c(0,32)) +   # label the x axis only at the window values
    annotate("text", x = 10, y = A-0.5, label = error_caption) +  # add the error line label
    opts(title="Trumpet curve for Test Data")
```

[image: Final Trumpet Graph]

Also available hYou can see the final graph [here][2]

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently try to solve trumpet curve calculation error. based on  IEC 60601-2-24 : 1998 - SECTION EIGHT – ACCURACY OF OPERATING DATA
AND PROTECTION AGAINST HAZARDOUS OUTPUT. here my R code :

```
    flow<-read.table("c:\\ciringe.txt",comment.char="#",header=TRUE)
    #parameters
    # setflow = 1 
    # P = 1,2,5,11,19,31

    P1<-1
    P2<-2
    P5<-5 
    P11<-11
    P19<- 19
    P31<-31 

    P1m = ((60 - P1) / 0.5 ) + 1
    P2m = ((60 - P2) / 0.5 ) + 1
    P5m = ((60 - P5) / 0.5 ) + 1
    P11m = ((60 - P11) / 0.5 ) + 1
    P19m = ((60 - P19) / 0.5 ) + 1
    P31m = ((60 - P31) / 0.5 ) + 1


    setflow<-1
    mQE1<-0.5
    mQE2<-0.25
    mQE5<-0.1
    mQE11<-0.045
    mQE19<-0.0263
    mQE31<-0.0161

    Q<-as.data.frame(c(0,(60*diff(flow$wt,1,1)/0.5*0.998)))  # Q is used for    flow in  the standard
   names(Q)<-"Q"
   # Now combine them
   l<-list(flow,Q)
   dflow<-as.data.frame(l)
   t1flow<-subset(dflow, dflow$secs>=3600 & dflow$secs<=7200) # require the   second hour of the data

   #overall 
   t1flow$QE<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100)   # calculate the error

   t1flow$QE1<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100)  * mQE1 # calculate the   error
   t1flow$QE2<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100) * mQE2  # calculate the error
   t1flow$QE5<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100) * mQE5 # calculate the error
   t1flow$QE11<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100) * mQE11  # calculate the error
   t1flow$QE19<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100) * mQE19  # calculate the error
   t1flow$QE31<-(((t1flow$Q-setflow)/setflow)*100) * mQE31  # calculate the error

   library(TTR) # use this for moving averages
   # 
   # Avert your eyes!  I know there must be a slicker way of doing this .....
   #     
   # Calculate the moving average using a sample rate of every
   # 4 readings (2 mins of 30sec readings)

   # now for the 1 minute window
   QE1<-SMA(t1flow$QE1,2)
   minQE1<-min(QE1,na.rm=TRUE)
   maxQE1<-max(QE1,na.rm=TRUE)

   # now for the 2 minute window


   QE2<-SMA(t1flow$QE2,4)
   minQE2<-min(QE2,na.rm=TRUE)
   maxQE2<-max(QE2,na.rm=TRUE)

   # now for the 5 minute window

   QE5<-SMA(t1flow$QE5,10)
   minQE5<-min(QE5,na.rm=TRUE)
   maxQE5<-max(QE5,na.rm=TRUE)

   # Set window to 11 mins

   QE11<-SMA(t1flow$QE11,22)
   minQE11<-min(QE11,na.rm=TRUE)
   maxQE11<-max(QE11,na.rm=TRUE)

   # Set window to 19 mins

   QE19<-SMA(t1flow$QE19,38)
   minQE19<-min(QE19,na.rm=TRUE)
   maxQE19<-max(QE19,na.rm=TRUE)

   # Set window to 31 mins


   QE31<-SMA(t1flow$QE31,62)
   minQE31<-min(QE31,na.rm=TRUE)
   maxQE31<-max(QE31,na.rm=TRUE)

   # 
   # OK - you can look again :-)
   #
   # create a data frame from this data
   trump<-    data.frame(c(1,2,5,11,19,31),c(minQE1,minQE2,minQE5,minQE11,minQE19,minQE31), c(maxQE1,maxQE2,maxQE5,maxQE11,maxQE19,maxQE31))
   names(trump)<-c("T","minE","maxE")
   A<-mean(t1flow$QE) # calculate the overall mean percentage error
   error_caption<-paste("overall percentage error = ",A,"%") # create the    string to label the error line
   # plot the graph
   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(trump, aes(x = T, y = minE)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point(color="red") +
   geom_line(aes(y = maxE)) +
   geom_point(aes(y = maxE),colour="red") +
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype = "dashed") + # overall percentage error
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept = A), linetype = "solid") + # set rate
    xlab("Observation windows (in minutes)") +
    ylab("% error") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,5,11,19,31),limits=c(0,32)) +   # label   the x axis only at the window values
    annotate("text", x = 10, y = A-0.5, label = error_caption)   # add the   error line label
```

actually, i'm not understand summation series as stated in the ISO docs (percentage variation)

Answer (score 0):

Your formulae don't match the equations in ISO 60601-2-24.  The spec is a bit tedious to go thru but there are no 2-minute windows or moving averages.  First, get your data formatted as 1-minute samples (per the spec).  Do a data array with 1 minute intervals and columns of:

```
colTotalLiquid = 1  #total liquid  (precalculated from weight)
colProgRate = 2         #prog rate
colQi   = 3         # rate Q(i) from IEC60601-2-24


obsWindow = (2, 5, 11, 19, 31)                  # observation windows in minutes
analysisT1start = 60                            # start of analysis period T1
analysisT1end = 120                             # end of analysis period T1

t1err = dict.fromkeys(obsWindow, None)

progRate = data[analysisT1start][colProgRate]
A = 100 * (((data[analysisT1end][colTotalLiquid] - data[analysisT1start][colTotalLiquid]) * hours / (analysisT1end - analysisT1start)) - progRate) / progRate

t1TrumpetX = []     #mintes
t1TrumpetY1 = []    #Ep(max)
t1TrumpetY2 = []    #Ep(min)
t1TrumpetY3 = []    #mean err
t1TrumpetY4 = []    #prog Rate

for p in obsWindow:
    m = (analysisT1end - analysisT1start) - p + 1
    t1err[p] = {'m': m} 
    EpMax = 0
    EpMin = 0
    for j in range(1, m + 1):
        errSum = 0
        for i in range(j, j + p):
            errSum += (1.0/p) * 100 * ( data[analysisT1start + i][colQi] - progRate ) / progRate
        if errSum > EpMax:
            EpMax = errSum
        if errSum < EpMin:
            EpMin = errSum
    t1err[p]['EpMax'] = EpMax
    t1err[p]['EpMin'] = EpMin
    t1TrumpetX.append(p)
    t1TrumpetY1.append(EpMax)
    t1TrumpetY2.append(EpMin)
    t1TrumpetY3.append(A)
    t1TrumpetY4.append(0)

tplot = PdfPages('trumpet curve.pdf')
p1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t1TrumpetX, t1TrumpetY1)
plt.plot(t1TrumpetX, t1TrumpetY2)
plt.plot(t1TrumpetX, t1TrumpetY3)
plt.plot(t1TrumpetX, t1TrumpetY4, '--')
plt.legend(('Ep(max)','Ep(min)', 'overall error', 'set rate'), fontsize='xx-small', loc='best')
plt.title(baseName + ': IEC60601-2-24 Trumpet Curve for Second Hour', fontsize='x-small')
plt.xlabel('Observation window (min)', fontsize='x-small')
plt.ylabel('Percentage error of flow', fontsize='x-small')
plt.ylim((-15, 15))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(obsWindow)
tplot.savefig(p1)
plt.close(p1)
tplot.close(p1)
```

That should get you the standard's trumpet curve.  There's no requirement to put a numerical label on the overall error A, but you could do that with an annotation.